# AWS t3.medium web traffic

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, web-server, linux-networking, amazon-instance-store

I have a ecommerce website running on t3.medium instance. Is there a way to find out how much web traffic can be handled by same in numbers? So if our web traffic increases do we need to buy another server?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: You will need to benchmark your server. T3 instances have a CPU credit system, if your instance runs out of CPU credits (monitor in CloudWatch) you might be better with a M series VM. You should also consider autoscaling your web server, which often works well with an AWS RDS managed database.